# How to safely encode PHP string into alphanumeric only?

Tags: php, encoding

How to safely encode PHP string into **alphanumeric** only string?
E.g. "Hey123 & 5" could become "ed9e0333" or may be something better looking
It's not about stripping characters, its about encoding.

The goal is to make any string after this encoding suitable for css id string (alnum),
but later I will need to decode it back and get the **original** string.

Comment: Isn't this going to make debugging your HTML/CSS unnecessarily hard if your element ids are not human-readable strings?

Comment: this is an ajax tree where ids are used for parent-child relation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`bin2hex`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) seems to fit the bill (although not as compact as some other encodings). Also take care that CSS ids cannot start with a number, so to be sure you'll need to prefix something to the `bin2hex` result before you have your final ID.

For the reverse (decoding), there's no such thing as `hex2bin`, but someone on the PHP documentation site suggested this (untested):

```
$bin_str = pack("H*" , $hex_str);
```

Comment: I tested the 'pack' function, and works like a charm! I even used the pair bin2hex/pack to encode and decode 'mcrypt_encrypt' output. Worked flawlessly every time.

Comment: hex2bin() is available from PHP 5.4.0

Answer (score -2):

This thread is dead for long time, but I was looking for solution to this problem and found this thread, someone might find the easy answer useful.

My solution is:

```
str_replace('=', '_', base64_encode($data));
```

Comment: base64 can also contain `+` and `/` so this solution is not 100% correct

Comment: and contain as well `=`

Answer (score -3):

You can use BASE64 encoding

http://php.net/manual/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: After base64_encode there is '=' character in the end of string, not 100% alphanumeric